# Selenium Webdriver - elements only with exact value identification , js/html

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, selenium

I am wondering about one thing. 
Have a UI html table with two records and would like to click on a record only with exact value.

Something like for instance:
SELECT record WHERE tr data-user LIKE "testuser1"

Is it possible to do that in some simple way ?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
         </th>
         <th data-sort="status">Status
            <i class="fa fa-sort-"></i>
         </th>
         <th data-sort="name">Name
            <i class="fa fa-sort-"></i>
         </th>
         <th data-sort="position">Position
            <i class="fa fa-sort-"></i>
         </th>
         <th data-sort="userCode">ID
            <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
         </th>
         <th data-sort="email">e-mail
            <i class="fa fa-sort-"></i>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr data-user="testuser1">
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="toggle btn btn-default off btn-sm" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 76px; height: 30px;">
               <input data-user-code="a.anpilov" class="status-toggle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-size="small">
               <div class="toggle-group">
                  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm toggle-on">Active</label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm active toggle-off">Inactive</label><span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default btn-sm"></span></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser1
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser1
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser1
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser1
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-user="testuser2">
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="toggle btn btn-default off btn-sm" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 76px; height: 30px;">
               <input data-user-code="a.puchaujara" class="status-toggle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-size="small">
               <div class="toggle-group">
                  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm toggle-on">Active</label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm active toggle-off">Inactive</label><span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default btn-sm"></span></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser2
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser2
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser2
         </td>
         <td class="plain">
            testuser2
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Tried to do it like that:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content'//div[@class='container'//table[@class='table table-striped'//following::tbody//tr[@data-user='testuser1']")).click();
```

but did not work ... :(

Comment: Instead of using the grave character to format a bunch of lines as code, indent each line 4 spaces and it will format it as a block. It looks neater. I would also recommend using an online HTML formatter to properly (and quickly) indent the HTML to make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use xpath expression using value attribute. For example, to select certain element with id and value and click on it:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + yourId + "' and @value='" + yourValue + "']")).click();
```

Or a td whith a text inside (be aware that td tag has no value, it has a text inside):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='" + yourTdText + "']")).click();
```

If you can build an unique xpath to identify what you are looking for this should be your best option even if you don't know the id or the tag type.

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie in webdriver,  the solution provided by you did not work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Have updated above code (maybe missed something last time).                                                          Could you please write down ready example ?

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the second example for td with text. It wasn't right. I think it's fine now.

Comment: Stil not working. I am doing something like that:         getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='testuser1']"));

Comment: Sorry i forget about the click action, i've updated again my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Subject to close.
Final solution:

`getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@data-user='testuser1']")).click();`

Comment: You can also use CSS Selectors... `getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("tr[data-user='testuser1']")).click();` XPaths are generally slower to execute.